# linux command line to access another linux machine

Tags: linux

how is it possible to access one linux machine thru another. Following is the need

1) check if a linux machine say ab-080 exists or not.

2) if exists, then clean a directory. /tmp ( this can be done using tmpwatch or rm ...)

not aware at present of a command like the one in windows \unc path.....what is it.

Brgds,

kNish

Comment: Define "exists".

Comment: ssh? <!--padding-->

Comment: ssh, expect, NFS, Samba... (depends on what experience you want)

Comment: @Ignacio: _so existential o.0_

Comment: @Matt - Hah, well played. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ssh ab-080 rm -r "/tmp/*"`

Comment: you should probably escape or quote the `*`: `ssh ab-080 'rm -r /tmp/*'`

Comment: good catch. that's what I get for writing in a hurry.